# Required products option laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, e-commerce, relationships

I am building an e-commerce app with laravel 4
I am lost with the correct way to manage taxes and options.
Here is what i have done in database :

```
products table: id,name,price,id_taxe
Got a tax table : id,name,rate
```

Very simple to manage this with laravel models

But troubles comes from that part :

Product must have an option with own price and tax rate (not the same than product), option have min and max quantity depending the product choosed.

Examples

If i bought products 1 (100 USD), option 1 is required at least 1 quantity (min) up to 10 products (max), if i bought 11 x products 1, option 1 is required at least 2 quantity.

If i bought products 2 (200 USD), option 1 is required at least 1 quantity up to 5 products.

I don't know how to manage this in a correct way.

Should i create option like a product in products table ?
How to link products with options (including min and max constraint) using laravel relationship.

Thanks for help.

Comment: You are talking about 'option' and 'option 1', what do you mean by that exactly? What constraints are there on buying the product, what I got from your question is this:  You want to have a min/max amount to be bought for each product. But then I read this: "How to link products with options (including min and max constraint)". Which indicates there is more to this 'option' than you can make out from the question.

Comment: For the moment there is only one option available for every products but i can change later, constraint is when i bought a product i bought also a number of option with depends of products, for example max option for product1 is 10, if i bought 11 products, 11/10 = 1.1, min option quantity is 2 and max is 10 (1 per products), more clear ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allright, I'll give it a go.

Based on your comments the best way to go seems to link the options through a  pivot table, also in this pivot table should be the number that indicates how many of these options you receive for each x amount of products ordered.

Migration:

```
Schema::create('product_options', function(Blueprint $table){
 $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
 $table->integer('option_id')->unsigned();

 $table->integer('per_x_products');

 $table->foreign('product_id')
  ->references('id')->on('products')
  ->onDelete('cascade')
  ->onUpdate('cascade');
 $table->foreign('option_id')
  ->references('id')->on('options')
  ->onDelete('cascade')
  ->onUpdate('cascade');
}
```

Relation in products table:

```
public function options(){
 return $this->belongsToMany('Option', 'product_options','product_id','option_id')
  ->withPivot(['per_x_products']);
}
```

Upon order of a product you get the id of the product and the amount ordered. You can now get the product, the related option(s) and the amount of ordered products on which the options increment.

```
$product = Product::find($id);

foreach($product->options as $option){

 $perXProducts = $option->pivot->per_x_products

 $minusThis = $amountOrdered % $perXProducts;

 $amountOfOptions = ($amountOrdered - $minusThis) / $perXProducts;

 $optionAmountsById[$option->id] = $amountOfOptions;
}
```

Can you try the above and see how far you get, this is all of the top of my mind so there might be some bugs in there. Also take a look here:

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables

Comment: Hi,great solution to solve my problems thanks, will try to implement this with my others troubles (see my other question).Many thanks.